# How can I target these children divs with one selector?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a CSS menu that has multiple levels. On this level I have a div with IDs for each topic(Bar,Pie, Line, ect). Is there a way I can style all of these divs in one place rather than having to name each individual ID and place the same styles?
I figure I need some sort of wrapper, but im unsure of where to place it and how I would call it correctly in my stylesheet.

My code:

```html
<div class="menu">
    <input id="s" name="UItab" type="radio" />
    <label for="s">
        <a href=""><span>Styles</span></a>
    </label>

    <div>
        <div onmouseout=
        "((collapseFlag == true) ? collapse('&lt;?php echo $secondMenu?&gt;'): expand());"
        onmouseover="expand('sub-menu');">
            <div id="sub-menu">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Item1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="">Item2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="sAdminEd" onmouseout=
        "((collapseFlag == true) ? collapse('&lt;?php echo $secondMenu?&gt;'): expand());"
        onmouseover="expand('&lt;?php echo $secondMenu?&gt;');">
            <div id="second-sub-menu">
                <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Item1</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="">Item2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="Bar">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Item1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="">Item2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="Pies">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Item1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="">Item2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="Line">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Item1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="">Item2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="Table">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Item1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="">Item2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="Gauge">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Item1</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="">Item2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Bar {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}

#Pies {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 20%;
}

#Line {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}


#Table {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}


#Gauge {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}
```

Comment: why not just add the same class to each and use that class to give the same styles to those elements?

Comment: This is exactly what CSS classes are for...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
#Bar,#Pies,#Line,#Table,#Gauge {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Chris' comment is the way to do it. Add a [CSS class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors) to the relevant elements and target it that way. That's exactly what classes are for in CSS--targeting a group of similar elements.

```css
.chartType {
    display:none;
    border: 1px solid #808080;
    right:0;
    top:57px;
    background-image: url('../images/background4.png');
    text-align: center;
    min-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    height: 20%;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
<input type="radio" name="UItab" id="s" >
<label for="s"><a href=""><span>Styles</span></a></label>
    <div>
        <div onmouseover="expand('sub-menu');" onmouseout="((collapseFlag == true) ? collapse('<?php echo $secondMenu?>'): expand());">
            <div id="sub-menu">
                <ul class="sub-menu">
                    <li ><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                    <li ><a href="">Item2</a></li>          
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="sAdminEd" onmouseover= "expand('<?php echo $secondMenu?>');" onmouseout ="((collapseFlag == true) ? collapse('<?php echo $secondMenu?>'): expand());">
            <div id="second-sub-menu">
                <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                    <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>       
                </ul>   
            </div>                  
        </div>  
        <div id="Bar" class="chartType">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Pies" class="chartType">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>   
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Line" class="chartType">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Item2</a></li>                           
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Table" class="chartType">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li ><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li ><a href="">Item2</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="Gauge" class="chartType">
            <ul class="second-sub-menu">
                <li ><a href="">Item1</a></li>
                <li ><a href="">Item2</a></li>  
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```